# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get' The entry.get is returning this error

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am using tkinter for my work. This is my code where the entry.get() doesn't work. I don't know what the error is for as this has worked previously in my work.

```
from tkinter import *
def please():
    print (entry_2.get())#The error

window_2=Tk()
label_6=Label(window_2, text="New Username", font="Calibri 12 
bold").grid(column=0)
label_7=Label(window_2, text="New Password", font="Calibri 12 
bold").grid(row=1)
entry_1=Entry(window_2, font="Calibri 12 bold").grid(row=0, column=1)

#This is the entry toget the contents
entry_2=Entry(window_2, font="Calibri 12 bold", show="*").grid(row=1, 
column=1)
label_address=Label(window_2, text="Address", font="Calibri 12 bold"). 
grid(row=2, column=0)
entry_address=Entry(window_2, font="Calibri 12 bold").grid(row=2, column=1)
label_dob=Label(window_2, text="Date Of Birth e.g.DD/MM/YEAR", font="Calibri 
12 bold"). grid(row=3, column=0)
entry_dob=Entry(window_2, font="Calibri 12 bold").grid(row=3, column=1)
label_gender=Label(window_2, text="Gender e.g. Male/Female/Other", 
font="Calibri 12 bold").grid(row=4, column=0)
entry_gender=Entry(window_2, font="Calibri 12 bold").grid(row=4, column=1)
label_interests=Label(window_2, text="Interests", font="Calibri 12 
bold").grid(row=5, column=0)
entry_interests=Entry(window_2, font="Calibri 12 bold").grid(row=5, 
column=1)
button_3=Button(window_2, text="Create", font="Calibri 12 bold", 
command=please).grid(row=6, column=1)
window_2.mainloop()
```

Comment: What debugging have you done? Have you checked what `Entry(window_2, font="Calibri 12 bold", show="*")` alone returns? It must be the call to `grid` that causes the None.

Comment: Have you tried making the entry_2 variable a global?

Comment: If the given answer answers your question, you should accept it to thank the person who helped you, and mark the question as solved.

Comment: This is a duplicate of [Tkinter: AttributeError: NoneType object has no attribute get](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101750/tkinter-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-get)

Comment: Please don't deface your posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to apply the grid method on a different line as the grid function returns None so `button3` is being None.

```
button_3=Button(window_2, text="Create", font="Calibri 12 bold", 
command=please)

button_3.grid(row=6, column=1)
```

Same for `entry2` and all others that defined like that.

```
entry_2=Entry(window_2, font="Calibri 12 bold", show="*")

entry_2.grid(row=1, column=1)
```